# How to run RMST protocol

Tags: ns2

I tried to run the rmst protocol's tcl file with tcl file used for creating the nodes to see the nodes and to see how tha packets are transmitted relaibly from one node to another. How can I see when the data is transferred from one node to another node in a reliable manner for RMST protocol??

Answer (score 0):

Suggest : Use APP-Tool for analyzing the trace file : a) "Instantaneous Throughput for a specific flow". b) "Instantaneous Goodput for a specific flow".

Please specify the following in the dialog : Source node, Destination node, Flow id, Tic interval.

APP-Tool  http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html → → 
https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

Comment: How can I use APP-Tool for analyzing the trace file?

Comment: Get APP-Tool : `$ git clone https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool.git` ... Please read the file README.md : Install python-gi, python-matplotlib. `cd APP-Tool/ && python GUI_Main.py` ... and the GUI will open. Copy trace files.tr to `APP-Tool/` for easy selection. Also read : http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html